# jQuery.easing[this.easing] for Magento2 Custom Theme

Tags: magento2, error, jquery, requirejs

I am making a custom theme and for no reason at all, I am now getting :

jQuery.easing[this.easing]

I wasnt previously getting this. Any Ideas?

Below is my requirejs config file:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*' : {
            owlcarousel  : 'js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel',
            easing:        'jquery/jquery-ui',
            customscript : 'js/custom'
        }
    },
    paths:{

            'owlcarousel'  : 'js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel',
            'easing':        'jquery/jquery-ui',
            'customscript' : 'js/custom'


    },
    shim: {
           'owlcarousel': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'easing': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'customscript': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            }
    }
};


    require([
        'jquery',
        'easing',
        'owlcarousel',
        'customscript',
    ], function ($) {  

          $(document).ready(function () {

            // -- Hero Carousel
           $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
                nav: true,
                items: 1,
                loop:true,
                autoplay:true,
                autoplayTimeout:3000,
                autoplaySpeed: 3000,
                autoplayHoverPause:true
            });

           // -- Sub Navigation

           openSubNav($);

        });
    });
```

The Problem occurs when I am calling the function  `openSubNav($);` however it has previously worked. I added jquery ui to the map after a previous suggestion but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I am not sure why it worked before and not now, however the `slideToggle` function in my `custom.js` file I added

**`slideToggle('slow', 'linear' function(){} );`**

The linear was the addition that made it work.

Hope this is useful to someone